# Apollo React GraphQL VariableTypeMismatch error

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I've got a mutation that looks like this:

```
mutation ADD_CATEGORY($id: ID!, $category: ID!) {
  addCategory(id: $id, category: $category)
}
```

It is passed into my React component as `addCategory`.

My `handleSave` function looks like this:

```js
    handleSave = () => {
      const { id, category } = this.state;
      addCategory({ variables: { id, category: category.id } });
    }
```

`id` and `category.id` are a string property on `this.state` object.

I get the following error:

> [GraphQL error]: Message: Validation error of type
>   VariableTypeMismatch: Variable type doesn't match, Location: [object
>   Object], Path: null

Looking at the API from GraphiQL I see that the `updateCategory` mutation has the following arguments:

```
id: ID!
category: [ID!]!
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure `addCategory` schema accepting `String` type for `id` & `category`.  From your API output looks like `category` is `Array` type.